# The limit of $k^n$ with $0<k<1$ equals $0$ as $n \to \infty$. I need reference of this proof.

Tags: calculus

I am working with a theorem and i need the reference of the above limit.
Kindly guide.

Answer (score 1):

Not too hard to prove it from first principles.

We have to prove $$\forall \epsilon > 0: \exists N: \forall n > N: |k^n - 0|< \epsilon$$

which is the same as saying

$$\forall \epsilon > 0: \exists N: \forall n > N: k^n< \epsilon$$

**Proof:**

Pick $\epsilon > 0$. Then, pick any $$N > \frac{\log \epsilon}{\log k}$$

For $n > N$, we have:

$$n > \frac{\log \epsilon}{\log k} \implies n \log k  < \log \epsilon$$
$$\implies \log k^n < \log \epsilon$$

$$\implies k^n < \epsilon \quad$$

where we used that $ \log k < 0$ for $k \in (0,1)$, so the inequality sign reverses and where we also used that $\log$ is a strictly increasing function.

This ends the proof.

Answer (score 1):

$0<k<1$,  then $1/k >1.$

$1/k= :(1+x)$,  with $x \gt 0.$

$(1/k)^n = (1+x)^n \ge 1 +nx.$
(Bernouilli's inequality)

Let $M \gt 1/\epsilon.$

Choose $n_0$ such that $1+n_0x  \gt M.$
(Archimedes)

For $n \ge n_0 :$

$(1/k)^n = (1+x)^n \ge 1+nx \gt M \gt 1/\epsilon$,

$\rightarrow$

$k^n \lt \epsilon$.

Answer (score 0):

Make use of the monotone convergence theorem.

From Wikipedia:

*If a sequence of real numbers is decreasing and bounded below, then its infimum is the limit.*

So you'll need to show that $0$ is the infimum of the sequence and that this sequence is decreasing.

*Hint*: Show that for any $n\in \mathbb{N}, k^{n+1} \lt k^{n} $ and also that $\forall \epsilon >0, \exists N\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $k^{N} \lt \epsilon.$